# use callback function in $.each then loop doesn't wait for function complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var modulesDemo = ['module1', 'module2'];
var moduleHtml='', pdfContent='';
```

$.each(modulesDemo, function( index, module ) {

```
if(typeof window[module] === 'function'){

    window[module](function(content){
        moduleHtml  +=content;

        if(modulesDemo.length==index+1){
            pdfContent += '<table>';
            pdfContent += moduleHtml;
            pdfContent += '</table>';

            console.log(pdfContent);
        }
    });

}
```

});

```
function module1(callback){
    var content=''; 
    var canvas = $("#demoCanvas")[0];
    var img    = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    content += '<tr>';
    content += '<td>';
    content += '<img style="width:100%;height:100%;margin-top:20px !important" src="'+img+'" />';
    content += '</td>';
    content += '</tr>';
    callback(content);
}

function module2(callback){
    function module2(callback){
    var img;
    var content;
    html2canvas($("#demoCanvas1"), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            img    = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            content += '<tr>';
            content += '<td>';
            content += '<img style="width:100%;height:100%;margin-top:20px !important" src="'+img+'" />';
            content += '<td>';
            content += '</tr>';
            //alert(2);
            callback(content);
        }
    });
}
}

<!-- language: lang-html -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <canvas id='demoCanvas'></canvas>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

when i am using callback in $.each then loop is not working synchronous.Iterate doesn't wait for function complete.Can anyone help me.

Every effort will be appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: here in $each, you have synchronously register the callbacks, but in what order they would be called is not guaranteed.

Comment: So what is the symptom of the problem, moduleHtml is in the wrong order?

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the functions as `module1` and `module2` but in `modulesDemo` array you are putting names as:

```
var modulesDemo = ["module_1","module_2"];
```

These names are different than the actual function names (notice the underscores?). So your functions are not getting called.

Edit:
Based on your comment, your issue can not be reproduced. See the code snippet below.

```js
var modulesDemo = ['module1', 'module2'];
var moduleHtml='', pdfContent='';
$.each(modulesDemo, function( index, module ) {

    if(typeof window[module] === 'function'){

        window[module](function(content){
            moduleHtml  +=content;

            if(modulesDemo.length==index+1){
                pdfContent += '<table>';
                pdfContent += moduleHtml;
                pdfContent += '</table>';
                //$scope.exportDashboardProcess(pdfContent,layout,size);
                console.log(pdfContent);
            }
        });

    }



});

function module1(callback){
    var content=''; 
    var canvas = $("#demoCanvas")[0];
    var img    = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    content += '<tr>';
    content += '<td>';
    content += '<img style="width:100%;height:100%;margin-top:20px !important" src="'+img+'" />';
    content += '</td>';
    content += '</tr>';
    callback(content);
}

function module2(callback){
    var content='';

    var canvas = $("#demoCanvas")[0];
    var img    = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    content += '<tr>';
    content += '<td>';
    content += '<img style="width:100%;height:100%;margin-top:20px !important" src="'+img+'" />';
    content += '</td>';
    content += '</tr>';
    callback(content);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id='demoCanvas'></canvas>
```

Comment: sorry i corrected. var modulesDemo = ["module1","module2"];
I'm sorry I wrote it in a hurry

Comment: @yashkumar ok if that was a typing mistake, but in that case your issue can not be reproduced.